# ruby on rails のサンプルコードがたくさん載ってるサイト

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

railsのサンプルコードを
打ちまくって練習したいのですが
railsのサンプルコードがたくさん載ってるサイトとか
書籍とかないでしょうか

探したのですが、私の探し方が下手なのか見つかりません
小さなwebアプリをサンプルコードを参考に作りまくりたいです

Comment: どのようなことをする web アプリが良いのかなど、お求めのものをもう少し具体的にして頂けると良さそうです。回答がより客観的なものになるだろうからです。より詳しくはこちらのメタ投稿をご覧ください: [「『Xの一覧が知りたい』という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/19110)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます
どのようなことをするwebアプリかというより、なんでも数をこなしたい感じなのです

Answer (score 2):

GitHubの[Rails](https://github.com/topics/rails)トピックスはいかがでしょうか。
小さなwebアプリよりは大きな規模のアプリが多いかも知れませんが、
railsアプリの投稿数はかなり多く、規模も様々で、その場その場で必要とする規模の
アプリケーションがソース毎見つけやすいサイトだと思います。

Comment: 関連で [rails-tutorial](https://github.com/topics/rails-tutorial) トピックもありますね。

Comment: 失念してました。ありがとうございます。更にGistも含めるとかなり広大？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます
GitHub行ってきます